# Using flexbox to position unknown number of elements in a grid with min width per element

Tags: html, css, flexbox, handlebars.js, grid-layout

I am looping through a bunch of objects using Express handlebars and I need to positions them in a grid. However I do not know when to make a new row so I don't think I can use a table.

I basically want a flexible number of row items with a minimum width per item. I understand flexbox can help me achieve this. I've looked up some tutorials on using it but I can't seem to find one to help me with what I need to achieve.

Here's what I have so far:

```
<div class="Grid">
    {{#each projects}}
        <div class="Grid-cell project">
            <img class="projectMainImage" src="/mi/{{this.mainImage}}" />
        </div>
    {{/each}}
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
.Grid {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    align-content: flex-start;
}
.Grid-cell {
    flex: 1;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: did you try min-width on .Grid-cell ?  what's wrong with it if you did ?

Comment: @GCyrillus I think that worked! Thank you. Feel free to add this as an answer then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may add a min-width on the `.Grid-cell` element.

Without min-width, the widest element should give the min-width of that cell (image here).

To allow element to grow wide enough to fit its content, use the shorthand flex :   `flex: 1 1 auto;` or   `flex: 1 0 auto;`

demo below

```css
.Grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-content: flex-start;
}

.Grid-cell {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  min-width: 10vw;
  line-height: 10vw;
  border: solid;
  margin: 1em;
  text-align: center;
}

img {
  vertical-align: middle;
  /*eventually*/
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="Grid">
        <div class="Grid-cell project">
            <img class="projectMainImage" src="http://lorempixel.com/150/100" />
        </div>
        <div class="Grid-cell project">
            <img class="projectMainImage" src="http://lorempixel.com/150/100" />
        </div>
        <div class="Grid-cell project">
            <img class="projectMainImage" src="http://lorempixel.com/150/100" />
        </div>
        <div class="Grid-cell project">
            <img class="projectMainImage" src="http://lorempixel.com/150/100" />
        </div>
        <div class="Grid-cell project">
            <img class="projectMainImage" src="http://lorempixel.com/150/100" />
        </div>
        <div class="Grid-cell project">
            <img class="projectMainImage" src="http://lorempixel.com/150/100" />
        </div>
        <div class="Grid-cell project">
            <img class="projectMainImage" src="http://lorempixel.com/150/100" />
        </div>
        <div class="Grid-cell project">
            <img class="projectMainImage" src="http://lorempixel.com/250/100" />
        </div>
        <div class="Grid-cell project">
            <img class="projectMainImage" src="http://lorempixel.com/150/100" />
        </div>
        <div class="Grid-cell project">
            <img class="projectMainImage" src="http://lorempixel.com/150/100" />
        </div>
        <div class="Grid-cell project">
            <img class="projectMainImage" src="http://lorempixel.com/150/100" />
        </div>
        <div class="Grid-cell project">
            <img class="projectMainImage" src="http://lorempixel.com/150/100" />
        </div>
        <div class="Grid-cell project">
            <img class="projectMainImage" src="http://lorempixel.com/150/100" />
        </div>
        <div class="Grid-cell project">
            <img class="projectMainImage" src="http://lorempixel.com/150/100" />
        </div>
        <div class="Grid-cell project">
            <img class="projectMainImage" src="http://lorempixel.com/150/100" />
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great! Could you possibly explain to me what `box-sizing` does?

Comment: box-sizing includes borders and padding into box size calculation, ..  or not . see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing ;) this bit of code is from yours, it has no effects here